# How can i generate an histogram with a dataframe in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib to generate a chart using a dataframe. Now, instead of `plt.plot`, i would like to chart an histogram.

Here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#131722',dpi=155, figsize=(5, 3))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=6, facecolor='#131722')

Colors = [['#0400ff', '#FF0000'], ['#09ff00', '#ff8c00']]

for x in List:

    rate_buy = []
    total_buy = []

    for y in x['data']['bids']:
        rate_buy.append(y[0])
        total_buy.append(y[1])

    rBuys = pd.DataFrame({'buy': rate_buy})
    tBuys = pd.DataFrame({'total': total_buy})

    # Standard chart
    # plt.plot(rBuys.buy, tBuys.total, color=Colors[Index][0], linewidth=0.5, alpha=1, label='test')

    #I tried:
    hist.plot(rBuys.buy, tBuys.total, alpha=1, label='test')
    hist.plot(tBuys.buy, tBuys.total, alpha=1, label='test')
```

And here is a sample of the data i'm using on my dataframes:

```
    buy
0  9688
1  9687
2  9686
3  9685
4  9684
5  9683
6  9682
7  9681
8  9680
       total
0   0.569200
1   0.710133
2   1.625170
3   7.873332
4  10.702935
5  14.805066
6  17.395178
7  19.090624
8  24.004433
```

So, basically, on my x axis i should have `rBuys` and on the y axis i should have `tBuys`. Is it possible to do that? I tried `hist.plot(rBuys.buy, tBuys.total, color=Colors[Index][0], linewidth=0.5, alpha=1, label='test')` but it gave me a blank chart. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a bar plot, not a histogram.  `plt.bar(rBuys.buy, tBuys.total)`